# Enviando anexo com Flask-Mail

Tags: python, email, flask

Configurar o flask e testar foi rápido e fácil mas enviar anexo esta sendo muito difícil se não impossível. Alguém tem uma dica ou exemplo pra enviar anexos com Flask-Mail?

Meu código esta assim:

```
mail = Mail(app)
MAIL_CONFIG = app.config

msg = Message(
    assunto, 
    sender = (MAIL_CONFIG['MAIL_NAME'], MAIL_CONFIG['MAIL_USERNAME']),
    reply_to = MAIL_CONFIG['MAIL_NAME'] + '<' + MAIL_CONFIG['MAIL_USERNAME'] + '>', 
    recipients = destinatarios
    )

msg.body = texto
msg.html = mensagem

# arquivo = 'downloads/bbbb.txt'

# with app.open_resource(arquivo) as fp:
#   msg.attach(arquivo, "text/plain", fp.read())

mail.send(msg)
```

Se eu descomento as linhas comentadas tenho o seguinte erro:

> TypeError: normalize() argument 2 must be unicode, not str

Comment: O que já tentou até agora?

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se você por acaso setou `MAIL_ASCII_ATTACHMENTS = True`. Fazendo isso te obriga a usar o tipo *unicode* no nome do arquivo: `arquivo = u'downloads/bbbb.txt'` (note o `u` antes da string)

Ou você pode parar de usar `MAIL_ASCII_ATTACHMENTS = True` ( o default é `False`) e evitar arquivos com caracteres unicode no nome.